# reshape column to row in a particular sequence

Tags: r

I want to reshape a data from wide to long; I want each record in the second column, after reshape, to be under each of record in the first column. For example, consider this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=sample(1:10), b=sample(101:110))
```

I want to transform the table below

```
a   b
2   105
5   102
3   103
4   104
1   101
```

to the table

```
group   value
a   2
b   105
a   5
b   102
a   3
b   103
a   4
b   104
a   1
b   101
```

The `gather` function, on the other hand, will have the records of a and then b.

Comment: Not sure why it is downvoted. At least give a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `transpose` the data and concatenate

```
data.frame(group = names(df), value = c(t(df)))
```